# Error in dropdown component using material ui v1.0 beta 26

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I’m using Material UI v1.0 beta.26 and I’m facing an issue with the dropdown component,  in this new version you have to use the Select component combined with MenuItem.

My dropdown is populated when the app is render but when I choose any option from it I’m getting the following error:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'material-ui/Select';
import {MenuItem, MenuIcon} from 'material-ui/Menu';

//CONSTANTS
import {CREATE_LS_DISCOUNT_TYPE_DD} from './commons/constants';
import {CREATE_LS_OFFER_TYPE_DD} from './commons/constants';

import cr from '../styles/general.css';


export default class ExampleDropDown extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      DiscountTypeData: [],
      OfferTypeData: [],
      DiscountTypeState: '',
      OfferTypeState: ''
    };

    this.renderDiscountTypeOptions = this.renderDiscountTypeOptions.bind(this);
    this.renderOfferTypeOptions = this.renderOfferTypeOptions.bind(this);

    this.handleChangeDiscountType = this.handleChangeDiscountType.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeOfferType = this.handleChangeOfferType.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    fetch(CREATE_LS_DISCOUNT_TYPE_DD)
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findResponse => {
        console.log(findResponse);

        this.setState({
          DiscountTypeData: findResponse.discountTypes,
        });
      });
  }

  handleChangeDiscountType(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({ DiscountTypeState: (value)});

    fetch(CREATE_LS_OFFER_TYPE_DD)
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findResponse => {
        console.log(findResponse);

        this.setState({
          OfferTypeData: findResponse.offerTypes
        });
      });
  }

  handleChangeOfferType(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({ OfferTypeState: event.target.value });
  }

  renderDiscountTypeOptions() {
    return this.state.DiscountTypeData.map((dt) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          key={dt.id}
          value={dt.text}>
          {dt.text}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    });
  }

  renderOfferTypeOptions() {
    return this.state.OfferTypeData.map((dt) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          key={dt.offerTypeCode}
          value={dt.offerTypeDesc}>
          {dt.offerTypeDesc}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <div className={cr.container}>
        <div>
          <Select

            value={this.state.DiscountTypeState}
            onChange={this.handleChangeDiscountType}>
            {this.renderDiscountTypeOptions()}

          </Select>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div>
          <Select

            value={this.state.OfferTypeState}
            onChange={this.handleChangeOfferType}>
            {this.renderOfferTypeOptions()}

          </Select>
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }

}
```

in the following method (*handleChangeDiscountType*) if I leave it like this "this.setState({ DiscountTypeState: value})" I got the error in the screenshot above but if I change that line like this "this.setState({ DiscountTypeState: event.target.value}) it works so I want to understand why

```
  handleChangeDiscountType(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({ DiscountTypeState: value});

    fetch(CREATE_LS_OFFER_TYPE_DD + 1)
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findResponse => {
        console.log(findResponse);

        this.setState({
          OfferTypeData: findResponse.offerTypes
        });
      });
  }
```

also what I want to do is to get the index of my selection in order to pass it to my second web service call but I don't know how to do it, in the previous version of Material UI I just put "index" and works but in the new version ain't work so I want to know a new way to add that parameter.

```
fetch(CREATE_LS_OFFER_TYPE_DD + PASS INDEX HERE)
  .then(Response => Response.json())
  .then(findResponse => {
    console.log(findResponse);

    this.setState({
      OfferTypeData: findResponse.offerTypes
    });
  });
```

I'll appreciate any help with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onChange` handler provided to `Select` is invoked with a target that is enriched with `value` and `name`, so you need to pull value from `event.target`:

```js
handleChangeDiscountType(event) {
  const {
    DiscountTypeData
  } = this.state;

  // you're using the text property as the value, but you should probably use its id
  // still, here's how you'd find the item using the selected item's value
  const selectedDiscount = DiscountTypeData.filter(
    discount => discount.text === event.target.value,
  );

  // use a templated literal to specify the endpoint with the selected item's id
  fetch(`${CREATE_LS_OFFER_TYPE_DD}/${selectedDiscount.id}`)
    .then(Response => Response.json())
    .then(findResponse => {
      console.log(findResponse);

      this.setState({
        OfferTypeData: findResponse.offerTypes,
      });
    });
}
```

The reason your code was not working is because `onChange` is not invoked with a third parameter, so your use of `value` was setting state to `undefined`.

For more information, see the [Selects demo](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selects/).

Comment: Thank for your time Ken, one more question... As you can see in the Fetch method I'm adding a "1" but that is harcoded, in the previous version of material ui I just add index as a parameter and instead of 1 I put index, but if I do it like that i'm getting and undefined in my web service URL, like this: "http://localhost:8080/services/OfferType/getOfferTypesByDiscountTypeId/undefined" so depending on the index is the value at the end and the information is returning...

Comment: First of all, you're rendering the MenuItems with a key set to the array index, which is an anti-pattern, so you should find something unique to key these items.  Still, if you really need the array index, you can use `Array.prototype.findIndex` to find the item that matches `event.target.value`, but this is brittle if there are duplicate items in the array.

Comment: So the way I'm doing it is not right? Because in the examples the options on each dropdown are hardcoded, so I haven't found any dynamic example, what  would you suggest to make it ok. Sorry for so many questions but I'm new to React and Material UI

Comment: It depends.  Where are you getting your data for the dropdown?  Is there any unique identifier you can use as the key?  If so, use that.

Comment: I update the code and the way I was using the key, the data is coming from a web services like this " 0: {id: 1, text: "DISCOUNT (Pounds)"} " so now in the code I made something like this "key={dt.id}" but still don't know how to pass that id or key to this line "fetch(CREATE_LS_OFFER_TYPE_DD + 1)" instead of harcoding the number 1.